# Adding diagonal while partitioning polygon represented in DCEL in O(1) time

Tags: time-complexity, computational-geometry, graph-algorithm, polygons

Considering algorithm to partition a simple polygone into monotone pieces by Lee and Preparata i read that adding every new diagonal can be done in O(1) time if our polygon represented in DCEL. But i can't figure out how it can be done in that time.

I think we need to change face for O(n) halfedges. And we have only 1 diagonal, so its insertion takes O(n).